# C++ loop until random generation is equal to certain number

Tags: c++, loops, random, do-while

I am trying to do a loop that will keep looping until a generated number using srand is equal to a certain number that I want. What is the best way to go about this? I tried doing it with a do while loop but it isn't working. Example below

```
do{
num = rand()%10+1;
}while(x == 5);
cout << x;
```

The "x" number always equals to a random number but it wont always equal to 5 like how it should be in the statement

Comment: that code snippet makes little sense.

Comment: I'd start by setting `x` in that loop rather than some phantom `num`. Otherwise you might be waiting awhile. And since you're doing nothing with the number itself, why not just `while ((rand() % 10 + 1) != 5);` ? (comments about how this doesn't give every value between 1 and 10 a fighting chance withheld).

Comment: `cout << 5;` seems more appropriate, scrap the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do{
x = rand()%10+1; //Use number which changes
}while(x != 5);  //Use Not Equal to 5 !
cout << x;
```

or

```
x=5;
do{
num = rand()%10+1; 
}while(num != x);  //Check if x equals n
cout << num;
```